# OnDelete Firebase Trigger Does Not Fire

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use the OnDelete trigger for my Cloud Functions on Firebase. However, it does not fire when the data (channel_id node) is deleted. My current data structure is like this. [image]

Note: a user_id can have multiple channel_id under it, this image is just a schema. I am also running the following code to check whether the node of channel_id is deleted.

```
exports.deleteSubscriptionsFromFeed = functions.database.ref('/users_subscription/{userID}/{channelID}').onDelete(event => {
  let channelID = event.data.previous.key;
  let subscriberID = event.data.previous.ref.parent.key;
  console.log(channelID);
  console.log("here");
  ...
});
```

This does not get fired and I am trying to figure out how to make it work. For more information, I am also running an OnCreate funciton like so and it does fire. So I am not sure why OnDelete does not work.

```
exports.addSubscriptionsToFeed = functions.database.ref('/users_subscription/{userID}/{channelID}').onCreate(event => {
  let channelID = event.data.key;
  let subscriberID = event.data.ref.parent.key;
  ...
});
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What version is the firebase-functions node module, as shown in your package.json?

Comment: It says I am using 0.5.7 for firebase-functions and 4.2.1 for firebase-admin

Answer (score 3):

In order to get access to database triggers onCreate, onUpdate, and onDelete, you need to be using firebase-functions module 0.5.9 or later.  At the time of this writing, the latest is 0.6.0.  Please update your modules with `npm upgrade` or choose specific versions with something like this: `npm install firebase-functions@0.6.0` from the functions directory where your package.json lives.

You can stay up to date with the latest Firebase related features by following [@FirebaseRelease](https://twitter.com/FirebaseRelease) on twitter.  Cloud Functions for Firebase is in beta, so you can expect frequent updates as new features are added and bugs are fixed.

Also, the latest version of firebase-admin is 5.0.1, which is a dependency for firebase-functions 0.6.0.

Comment: Thanks! I ran it just now but it does not look like anything is downloading. I'm running npm upgrade from the functions folder where the package.json lives.

edit: I ran npm install firebase-functions@0.6.0 and npm install firebase-functions@5.0.1 separately and it downloaded. But the package.json file does not change the version number. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: It should definitely change package.json.  It does whenever I change versions.  I don't know why it wouldn't change...

Comment: I looked at the docs and I just ran these two lines instead: npm install --save firebase-functions and npm install -g firebase-tools. It does not update to 0.6.0 or 5.0.1 so does that mean it's not released yet?

Comment: nvm I got it to install the newest versions. @doug-stevenson even with the latest versions OnDelete is not being fired.

Comment: I just did a minimal test that logs a message in both onCreate and onDelete of a path `/foo/{id1}/{id2}` and they both got triggered when I set `/foo/x1/x2` to `true`, then deleted it.

Comment: That is super strange. And I assume that you are using the same path to listen to these events like I did in the post? It does not run for me no matter what I do for some reason. OnCreate will trigger but OnDelete does not

Comment: Maybe strip your functions down to just a log to ensure that nothing else is going on?

Comment: That was what I was doing. Do you know if OnDelete is called only if it is deleted or it is called when the data is set to null too? Currently my delete method is just updating a new dictionary that does not have the node in it. So it's not exactly "removed" but it is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

So figured out the problem is that OnDelete is not triggered when a root node is updated. For example, I was just setting the value of user_id with a new dictionary instead of explicitly removing or setting the value of a channel_id to null.

Comment: That's an update, not a delete.  A delete means that there is now no data at the location provided.